# Examples of convergence of series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, intuition

These questions are practice questions from the text "Advanced Calculus, Folland" chapter 6.2 (not HW)

I am working on some exercises on convergence of series and I feel that I understand it well but when I look at the answer guide for the book I am not so sure how the author got his answer.

1) test the convergence of series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sqrt {n+1}}{n^ 2-4n+5}$$

the answer in the text is :
${ a }_{ n }\sim { n }^{ -3/2 }\quad $ therefore converges by comparison to $\sum { { n }^{ -3/2 } } $

EDIT:
Is there any way to solve this using Root or Ratio test or using a Simple comparison test.

I am not sure how he got the others either but I am hoping if I can understand this one I will be able to understand the others.

Comment: Do you know the meaning of equivalence $\sim$? If so, this is indeed a powerful tool to determine absolute convergence/divergence by comparison with standard series such as the Riemann p-series. Be careful though with series whose general term does not have an eventually constant sign.

Comment: well the tools/theorems the chapter has provided me with are root test and ratio test mostly and a general comparison test. My understanding of equivalence is limited as I am terrible with abstract algebra.

Comment: Given two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ which are eventually nonzero, we say that they are equivalent if $a_n/b_n\longrightarrow 1$. In this case, we write $a_n\sim b_n$. If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are series with general terms of eventually constant sign, and if $a_n\sim b_n$, then $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum b_n$ converges. In such a case, convergence is absolute, of course, given the assumptions. A typical situation where this is most useful: $a_n=f(n)$ for a rational function $f=p/q$. You will see that the series converges if and only if $\deg q-\deg p\geq 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion is with the tilde. With your example, this is essentially saying what happens to our summand as $n \to \infty$. As $n \to \infty$, the numerator behaves like $\sqrt{n}$ and the denominator behaves like $n^2$ -- you are looking at the dominating terms. This allows us to say our summand "behaves like" $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$ as you say, which converges by comparison with the well known p-series (here, $p > 1$).

**Addendum after your edit:**
Root Test looks like it would fail since you get a result of $1$ when you take $n\to\infty$ of the $n$th root of $a_n$. I doubt the Ratio Test is of much use either, since the Root Test is actually a stronger result of the Ratio Test. Often the Ratio Test is helpful when you have factorials which are not present here.

**In general however, the Ratio and Root Test FAIL for polynomials -- you will always get an inconclusive result of $1$, which you then have to rely on other tests for convergence.**

Comment: Thankyou :) !!! this sorts it out.

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to upvote the answer if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps  little more precise for your book's answer:

$$\begin{align*}n^2-4n+5=(n-2)^2+1\\{}\\\sqrt{n+1}\stackrel{\text{for}\;n\ge 5}\le\sqrt{2(n-2)}\end{align*}\implies \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^2-4n+5}\le\frac{\sqrt{2(n-2)}}{(x-2)^2}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{(n-2)^{3/2}}$$

So by the comparison test our series converges.